# check_box helper doen't work from the form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, helper

I have Project class with :fulltime boolean attribute. So Project can be either fulltime or single project. Default: false.

For defining that I have check box in my Edit page:

```
=form_for [@user, @project] do |f|
.
.
.
    = f.check_box :fulltime
    %b Fulltime
```

My update action works just fine for other params, but not for :fulltime.
All I can do is define true/false from console.

Asking 4 ur kind help

Comment: Post your `params` generated after submitting the `form`.

Answer (score 0):

> Post your params generated after submitting the form

You pushed me to find an answer. I just forgot to permit :fulltime in params

```
def project_params
  params.require(:project).permit(:title, :content, :budget, :user_id, :fulltime)
end
```